# How do I get the p12 key for iOS so i can install my app on my Iphone to test it?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, developer-tools

This is not exactly a programming question and please move this to the right place or refer me right but this community has always been able to help me and I am sure someone else will have some use of the hopefully good answers this can deliver so I'll give it a shot.

How can I make an .p12 certificate which Phonegap needs to make my web app to an iOS app? I followed the Phoneapp documentation but that didn't get me anywhere and all the material on this question goes from 2012-2014 and no one knows how to make this p12 key and register it or associate it to your developer account with Apple. Do I really need to pay 100$ a year just to get this certificate?! This is madness... Am I the only one who thinks this way? I found no one who stood against this. I tolerate these costs in case I got a finished product to distribute, but I want to make this key just to see how my app looks on my iPhone and paying this is insane. Google's APK are free, how can hobby programmers be still so dominant on the app store?

Can I install an app on my iPhone without this certificate?

Comment: Please read the description of the apple tag before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the steps outlined in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206123/xcode-7-develop-for-ios-without-developer-account

Once you generate your Certificate it should show up in Keychain. From keychain you can export a p12.

More info at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. If you want to use Push Notification services than you must to enroll Apple Developer Program. (or You can try local notification.)

Comment: Such a shame that apple has such a monopoly on the apps on their platform. Very Well.. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Im not sure this is true, Apple lets you install apps on your own devices up to 5 i think for free now without a Apple Develop Program subscription.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. No where in his question does he mention APNS. @JohannesBotéus see j_mcnally answer below for installing iOS apps on a device without a developer account.

Comment: He doesn't mention APNS but .p12 file is about the APNS.

Comment: A [`p12` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) is a generic storage format for cryptographic certificates and keys, while you can use it APNS it doesn't mean that `p12` == `APNS`. The developer code signing credentials stored in your keychain can also be stored as a `p12` (as well as any item exported from the keychain).
While what you say in your answer is correct - you can only use APNS with a paid Apple Developer account its completely incorrect for the context of the original question.

Comment: I know but we don't use .p12 files except APNS while development process. I'm directly helping about this topic.

Comment: Most 3rd party build tools prefer p12 key stores since they wrap private and public keys. Phonegap / Cordova specifically use this keystore to codesign. Its fairly common once you step outside of xcode. Also you see it with APNS alot because 3rd parties use it as a standard keystore to wrap the certs in server side code.